# Save granted permissions in a Actions on Google app to avoid asking for it more than once

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

While building an app using actions-on-google, i ask user for device location.
I need google assistant to remember if user grants this permission to avoid asking for the same permission again when user uses the app later. How do I do this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Once the user grants you access to the information you need, you can store that information in UserStorage. That way you can check if a user has information stored in their UserStorage, before asking for a permission.

Please not that if you're storing personal data about the user, you may need to ask for their permission,not only to query the data but also to store it as well. As stated in the docs:

> Some countries have regulations that require developers to obtain
>   consent from the user before they can access, or save certain
>   information (e.g. personal information) in the userStorage. If you
>   operate in one of these countries and you want to access, or save such
>   information in userStorage, you must use the Confirmation helper to
>   ask consent to the user and obtain the consent before you can start
>   storing such information in userStorage.

You also need to state that you're saving data in your privacy policy:

> If you store the user's information, remember to disclose it in your
>   privacy policy when submitting your project for review.

As discussed in the comments. You **CAN'T** get users permission once and query their location multiple times. You need a new permission each time you query the data. If you suspect that users location might change every time they use your action (i.e. Actions that mainly target smart phones), you can handle it as a dialog turn. Here's an example:

> **System:** Would you like to know about the weather in $userSavedLocation?

If user says yes, no need for permission. If they say no, then ask for permission again.

Comment: Yes that can be done for information that does not change..but storing device location does not help in my use case as it might change and i need to make suggestions based on current location.

Comment: As Allen already said, we can't ask once and get the location multiple times. You need to ask for permission every time you make a new request. **EDIT:** I would handle it in the dialog. Like "Would you like to know the weather in $userSavedLocation?" If user says yes, the location hasn't changed, no need for another permission. If user says no, ask for permission. I would rather ask a yes/no question than to ask for permission each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't save the permission, but you can save the location as Yuksel has suggested.

This works well if you're expecting the location from a relatively fixed device such as a Google Home, but not as well if you're getting the location from a mobile device.

If you are planning to get the location from a mobile device, you need to request it each time.